# How we can extract text static contents from the webpage that contains button names, headings, span text, labels from CSHTML files

Tags: .net-core, static, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, translation

I need kind of code or a tool that can extract text static contents from the webpage that contains button names, headings, span text, labels, but not any dynamic content that is coming from database or api.

I am translating the website into multiple languages and need to translate the static text content manually for accuracy.

All the code is in cshtml files, that is dotnet 6 MVC.

for example:

```
<th class="text-center" style="vertical-align:middle">
    <span data-bind="text:absenceOption.fullDay.text">FirstText1</span>
<span data-bind="text:absenceOption.fullDay.text" style="color:#808080"></span>
    
   
    @if ((ViewBag.IsPowerAdmin != null && ViewBag.IsPowerAdmin == true)
       && (ViewBag.IsDistrictLevel != null && ViewBag.IsDistrictLevel == true))
    {
        <a id="type-fd-warn" class="setting-warn" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="0" role="button" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="top"
           data-content="<div style='width:240px;'><div><button id='fd' class='close tip-close' '><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div><div>There are missing translations for this absence type.<br />Would you like to <a id='fd' style='cursor:pointer' '>add them</a> now?</div></div>"
           data-html="true"></a>
    }
    else
    {
        <a id="type-fd-warn" class="setting-warn" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="0" role="button" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="top"
           data-content="<div style='width:240px;'><div><button id='fd' class='close tip-close' onclick='CloseTranslateTypeTip(this)'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div><div>There are missing translations for this absence type</div></div>"
           data-html="true"></a>
    }
  
    <a id="type-recommended-fd-warn" class="setting-warn2" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="0" role="button" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="top"
       data-content="<div style='width:240px;'><div><button id='fd' class='close tip-close' '><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div><div>This absence types exceeds the recommended number of options (4) presented to a parent at any given moment.</div></div>"
       data-html="true"></a>
    
    <span style="font-weight:normal" data-bind="text:'('+absenceOption.defaultText()+')'"></span>
    
    <span style="font-weight:normal;color:#808080" data-bind="text:'('+absenceOption.fullDay.defaultText()+')'">LASTTEXT</span>
   
</th>
```

I need kind of result like:

- FirstText1
- There are missing translations for this absence type.
- Would you like to
- add them
- now?
- There are missing translations for this absence type
- This absence types exceeds the recommended number of options (4) presented to a parent at any given moment
- LASTTEXT

Now i need kind of code(that takes cshtml extension files as input and gives above like result) or tool to do this because we have around hundreds of views and partial views in our project, and manually doing it takes lot of time.

Comment: I trust you are trying to achieve a feature to make you app could be friendly to different language speaking people, and I'm afraid [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-8.0) might help if you didn't know it. By the way, since this is an MVC project, all the content should be rendered in the server side, so no matter it's dynamically generated from database, or hardcode in cshtml, we should all treat it in server side. If we want to handle it in the client, like after a button click all the content

Comment: convert to a different language, then we need to use dom selector to get each of the element and try to translate the replace the content, it's complex and I don't think it a good idea.